# dxl script to check if an attribute has no data in it

Tags: ibm-doors

This is what i have so far.

> `Module m = current
>   load view "Standard view"
>   Object o = current`
>
> `//column attribute Proposed Change
>   insert(column 4)
>   attribute(column 4, "Proposed Change")
>   width(column 4, 100)`
>
> `//column attribute Object Type
>   insert(column 3)
>   attribute(column 3, "Object Type")
>   width(column 3, 100)
>   string txt = "Requirement"`
>
> `Filter f1 = contains(attribute "Object Type", txt, false, true)  //===Filter "Requirement" in Object Type
>   set f1
>   filtering on`

This give me just my attributes i want to see for my first step.

Im trying to figure out how to do an if statement so that the Proposed Change column will only show if there is any text in that column. (i.e. if string is empty then dont display Proposed Change Column, but if string is not empty then display the column) otherwise it would show an infoBox "There are no Proposed Changes"

I am very new to all this and so far what ive done has been self taught/read from the dxl manual.

Could anyone help me out or point me in the right direction as to what i should do next? the maunal has been confusing me on this subject.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "notNull" for this one -- see chapter 25: Display Control > Filters in the DXL manual. There are a lot of only-DXL not-other-language things in there, so it's worth skimming to see what you can do with it.

Here's how it might work:

```
Filter f_pc = notNull attribute "Proposed Change"
set f_pc
filtering on
```

And if you want to combine that with your other filter:

```
Filter f = f_pc && f1
set f
filtering on
```

Good luck with DXL. Try not to learn to much or else you'll be known as the DOORS Guy at work, and it's difficult to escape that.

Comment: appreciate the reply ill give this a try and thank you

Comment: and is there another dxl manual out somewhere i should be looking at? My chapter 25 is to do with Partitions

Comment: Right, didn't ask you which DOORS you were using -- I'm referring to v9.6.x - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf

Comment: Whoops. I mean Chapter 24 for v9.6. It's chapter 25 for v9.6.1. Didn't expect an outline change for a minor version change. Here's what I'm looking at: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf

Comment: cool ill read into that section some more, i really apprecaiate the help